# Unix like console for Windows (GIT)

Tags: windows, linux, git

Currently I am using windows version git software for git, I found it is really hard to copy and paste in the console, and the mouse middle key is not supported.

I used to putty SSH way to linux box then do things in putty, but at the moment I only have windows.

so does anyone know some tools enable end-users have UNIX console ? Mouse middle key and highlight supported is essential.

Thanks in advance for any advices.

---

Update: 
Downloaded virtualbox then install a copy of Linux..then samba... seems making things complicated but handy.

Comment: As a workaround, select/copy/paste is available in all Win32 console windows (even if it's not hosting a `cmd.exe` instance) by right-clicking the titlebar and using the `Edit` submenu.

Answer (score 3):

You should try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which has most basic command line tools from linux, and supports middle mouse pasting.

Comment: Don't be afraid of Cygwin-X either.  It is a little bit harder to setup.  But it will give you your mouse back.  Plus some other benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure there is an exact copy, but here is what I do:

1. Install MSYS and MinGW (also offers gcc compiler, etc)
   This gives me many useful linux commands (although not with as much features) such as ls, touch, cat, and you name it. If I need more functionality, say I just add more commands (say Grep, Git etc) by installing the tools, and adding them to the %PATH% environment variable.
2. A slightly better counterpart is the Windows PowerShell (Win 7 Pro). Give it a whirl...

Comment: Btw, you CAN paste with Right Click/Paste (not as handy, but then, Windows is not linux ;) )

Comment: You can also hit Alt-Space to pull up the terminal menu, edit and paste.  The selection can be done from the keyboard as well.  Once selection is done, hitting enter (and this will show on the menu) will copy it to the buffer.  If it is still the same as years ago, you can also do either shift-insert or control-insert to paste what you did copy to the buffer.

Comment: yup, that is pretty much what i do... never used Cygwin, (cuz had to chose between MinGW and cygwin for having gcc on Windows), but I'm more or less happy with what I have... :D

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the shortcut to `cmd.exe` (or the title bar of a running instance) and select *Properties*. In the *Options* tab check the *QuickEdit Mode* checkbox and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

With that modfication *left-click-drag* will select a rectangular section, and *right-click* will either copy the selection (when something is selected), or paste text from the clipboard (when nothing was selected). It's not quite as convenient as Unix/Linux terminals (because it's limited to block selections), but still a lot better than the default setting where you have to initiate each action via the context menu.

Using [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) might be another option.